# Exercise on diffuse and purely discrete measure

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

> **Problem:** Let $( \mathbb{X}, \mathcal{X})$ be a Borel space. Let $\lambda$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure on $\mathbb{X}$ and let $A:= \lbrace x \in \mathbb{X} : \lambda ( \lbrace x \rbrace ) =0 \rbrace$. Show that $\lambda_A:= \lambda (A \cap 
>  \cdot )$ is diffuse and that $\lambda_{A^C}$ is purely discrete

---

> **Hint:** Show that $A^c= \lbrace x \in \mathbb{X} : \lambda ( \lbrace x \rbrace ) > 0 \rbrace$ is at most countably infinite.

---

**My approach:** To show that $\lambda_A$ is diffuse is easy.

Let $x \in \mathbb{X}$ be arbitrary, if $x \notin A$ then  $\lbrace x \rbrace \cap A = \emptyset$ and clearly $\lambda_A( \lbrace x \rbrace )=0$

If $x \in A$ then $\lbrace x \rbrace \cap A = \lbrace x \rbrace$ and since $x \in A$ it follows that $\lambda_A ( \lbrace x \rbrace)=0$, thus $\lambda_A$ is diffuse.

The harder part for me is to show that $\lambda_{A^C}$ is purely discrete, most likely because of a lack of measure theory expertise.

Going for the hint I can say that since $\lambda$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure on $\mathbb{X}$ we have $\mathbb{X} = \bigcup X_i$ with $\lambda ( X_i) < \infty$ and therefore  $$A^c = \lbrace x \in \bigcup X_i : \lambda (\lbrace x \rbrace) > 0 \rbrace = \bigcup \lbrace x \in X_i : \lambda ( \lbrace x \rbrace ) > 0 \rbrace = \bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \xi_i $$
Since $\xi_i \subset X_i$ we have that $\lambda ( \xi_i) < \infty$, i.e. $$ \lambda ( \xi_i) = \int 1_{\xi_i} (x) \lambda (dx) < \infty $$
But I don't see how I could possibly continue from here. I haven't used the fact yet that $\mathbb{X}$ is a Borel Set, howoever I do not see how that would be useful here.

Comment: Since $\lambda(\xi_i)=m_i$ is finite, for each positive integer $n$, there are at most $nm_i$ points $x$ in $\xi_i$ such that $\lambda(\{x\})\geqslant\frac1n$ hence there at most countably many points in $\xi_i$ such that $\lambda(\{x\})\ne0$, qed.

Comment: Thanks @Did, do I understand it correctly, that the first part of your statement follows by the Chebyshev Inequality applied to the counting measure? i.e.
$$\# \{ x \in \xi_i : \lambda ( \{x \}) \geq 1/n \} \leq n \int_{\xi_i} \lambda \{ x \} d \# (x) = n \sum_{x \in \xi_i} \lambda ( \{ x \} ) \overset{?} \leq n \lambda ( \xi_i) $$

Comment: No Chebyshev inequality here, simply the remark that $$\bigcup_{x\in\xi_i,\lambda(\{x\})\geqslant1/n}\{x\}\subset\xi_i$$ and the additivity of $\lambda$.